# Не сохраняются httpOnly куки после запроса к API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Есть приложение на React, которое через Fetch делает POST запрос к API серверу на Express.

```
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: e.target.username.value,
            password: e.target.password.value
        })
    }
    fetch('http://192.168.100.2:4000/login', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data['status'] === 'ok') {
                navigate('/')
            }
         });
```

В запросе передается имя пользователя и пароль для авторизации на сайте. После чего на 2 сервере делается запрос к базе данных и создается JWT.

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}));

...

res.cookie('token', jwt.sign(payload, tokenKey), {
    httpOnly: true
})
res.send({
    status: "ok",
})
```

При успешной аутентификации токен должен сохраниться в httpOnly куки для последующих запросов, но он не сохраняется.

От сервера приходит такой ответ:
[image: 1]

Comment: Это Хром говорит, что не хочет принимать куку с другого сайта, потому что у неё не выставлен параметр SameSite=None. API сервер должен выставлять кукам такой параметр, если не против того, что запросы к нему идут с чужого сайта.

Comment: @ВикторКарев можно ли как то отключить это? Если выставить SameSite=None он просит параметр secure, а для него нужен https, которого вроде нет на localhost

Comment: Нельзя. Но ты можешь сохранять куки не через Set-Cookie в шапке, а скриптом. https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie